# WCF - detect error in response

Tags: c#, wcf, webservice-client

In WCF i use a synchronous call.

In the response the connection died. For sender is this ok, he get some exception and can rollback his actions.
But what is with the receiver. He did action - regarding the webcall - successfully, but he don't know that the sender thing, that receiver made his job not well [because of exception].
Is it possible that receiver detect the error in the response occurs?

I need a pattern that ensure that both sides has the correct knowledge of the state of the service call.
(Background is that two system has state machine and a change in one of them must be realized in the other too, or if a error in one of them occur - sounds like distributed transaction)

Comment: You can use fault contracts to inform the client of the type of fault.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider enlisting all your service operations in distributed transactions.

This will ensure you that when an operation fails, the transaction is rolled back across service boundary. Therefore if you rollback the transaction at the client, it will automatically roll back at the server as well (and the other way around).

Startup articles:

1. [WCF Transaction Propagation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163432.aspx)
2. [CodeProject sample.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38793/6-Steps-to-Enable-Transactions-in-WCF)

Although it seems something big to grasp, it is well worth the effort. It will simplify your error handling logic considerably.

**Note:** Since WCF transactions are actually native distributed transactions (managed by MSDTC) you will get an extra gain from this. The transactions will be (optionally) propagated to  SQL Server (if you use one) and all database operations will be in the same transaction as your service operations.

Comment: Agreed, if there is a reliance, then use transactions to ensure its an all-or-nothing approach.